Problems when trying to ananlyze spatial transcriptomics data with GSDensity
I tried to ananlyze my ST data with the code provided in this paper:
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-023-44206-x
However, I was stuck at this step:
res <- compute.kld(coembed = ce, genes.use = intersect(rownames(ce),
                                                       rownames(brain)), n.grids = 100, gene.set.list = gene.set.list,
                   gene.set.cutoff = 20, n.times = 100)

It showed "validate_input_optimal_anticlustering(x, K, "diversity", solver)：
The selected method can only be used for equal-sized groups"
Even when I used the seurat stxBrain data which used in the tutorial still encounter the same problem.
Does anyone have tried this code and have any idea how to fix this problem?
Thx
I used the seurat stxBrain data which used in the tutorial still encounter the same problem.
Does anyone have tried this code and have any idea how to fix this problem?

Just had this issue. Use anticlust version 0.6.1 and everything will work!
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/anticlust/anticlust_0.6.1.tar.gz

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
